# Independent random variable in the limit (need extension?)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Given a sequence of rv $(X_n)$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ with values on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ where $\mathcal{F}=\bigcup \mathcal{F}_n$ and $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_s:s\leq n)$. Lets say there is a random variable $X$ with values in $(E,\mathcal{E})$, and assume $X_n\xrightarrow{d} X$.
Assume that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n\leq x,B)=P(X\leq x)P(B) \tag1
$$
holds, for all continuity sets $A$ of the distribution function of $X$ and all $B$ in $\mathcal{F}$. 
We see, that $X$ is independent to $\mathcal{F}$.

However i whonder if this notation (1) is valid.

Can $X$ be defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$  if we require that (1) should hold?

Or has $X$ to be defined on an extension of $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$? Name this $X$ as $X*$.
An extension would be the canonical extension $\Omega\times E, \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{E}$ and $X*(\omega,x)=x$ the canonical version is of course independent of $\mathcal{F}$. The measure on that extension should be the productmeasure $P'(,)$, where the marginal $P'(\Omega,.)$ is the distribution of $X$.

The notation is from "Some simple conditions for limit theorems to be mixing" from Eagleson.
Eagleson starts with another version of (1), where he claims that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n\leq x,B)=F(x)P(B)
$$
should hold, where $F$ is the distribution function of $X$. Here $X$ is not mentoined to be on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.  However in theorem 1, he uses the notation in (1).
So i whonder what do i miss?

Comment: "We see, that X is indepen(den)t (of) F." Do we? Sorry but I do not see that.

Comment: @Did But doesnt (1) say, that the limit resulf of $X_n\rightarrow X$ stays true conditioned on $B$ with $P(B)>0$ for all $B\in\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: No, (1) is saying that, for every $B$ such that $P(B)\ne0$, $$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(X_n\leq x\mid B)=P(X\leq x).
$$ Nothing about $X$ and $B$ being dependent or independent in there. As you noted yourself $X_n\to X$ in distribution does not even imply that $X$ and $X_n$ are defined on a common probability space.

Comment: @Did ah ok there was my error in reasoning.  But if $X$ has not to be defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is  $P(X\leq x)$ then valid in the notation?

Comment: To be extra-rigorous one could write $\bar P(X\leqslant x)$ for $X$ defined on some probability space $(\bar\Omega,\bar{\mathcal F},\bar P)$. Nobody does, though.

Comment: @Did ok thanks. now it's clear